# Cuando subi mi app a algun servicio en la nube todo funcionaba bien, pero cuando recargo la pagina me devuelve not found 404 en cualquier ruta

Tags: reactjs

No entiendo el comportamiento de react router en produccion pero en local funciona muy bien cuando recargaba mi app. ahora que la subi a un servicio en la nube cada vez que recargo la pagina me devuelve un 404 not found

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      {/* inicia el login la peticion a la BDD */}
      <Routes>
        <Route index path="/" element={<Login />} />
        {/* de acuerdo a su rol debe redireccionarlo a la ruta indicada */}
        <Route
          path="/admin/*"
          element={
            <Proteccion actor="admin">
              <Admin />
            </Proteccion>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/facturador/*"
          element={
            <Proteccion actor="facturador">
              <Facturador />
            </Proteccion>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/recepcion/*"
          element={
            <Proteccion actor="recepcion">
              <Recepcion />
            </Proteccion>
          }
        />
        <Route path="/logout" element={<Logout />} />
        <Route path="/forgottenPassword" element={<OlvidoDeClave />} />
        <Route path="/*" element={<h1>Page not found 404</h1>} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Login.js

```
useEffect(()=>{
    isAutenticate()
  }, [])

  function isAutenticate(){
    if( sessionStorage.getItem("rol") && sessionStorage.getItem("token") )
      navigate( sessionStorage.getItem("rol") )
  }
```

este es mi useEffect. cuando recargo la pagina se invoca a un metodo isAutenticate() luego verifica que haya definido un rol y token en sessionStorage todo bien hasta esta parte pero en modo local. en la nube no funciona :(

Comment: Fíjate en la URL que indica la barra del navegador antes de refrescar u luego de refrescar. Quizás la diferencia que en el servicio se nube esta bajo un dominio que no lo tienes cuando estas en local o simplemente la url esta poniendo conservando el nombre de página /index por ejemplo como raíz y eso lo tienes como ewgla /* not found

Comment: ( https://app-pizza-38kx.onrender.com ) esta es la principal. muestra mi login si recargo se mantienen hay y todo funciona bien. pero cuando me logeo cambia a esta ( https://app-pizza-38kx.onrender.com/admin/dashboard ) por ejemplo. si en esta ruta actual le doy a recargar me devuelve un not found y se mantiene en la misma ruta no la cambia, incluso cambia el logo pequeño de la ventana.

Answer (score 0):

Ya conseguí una respuesta clara. estuve indagando un rato en la documentación y debo definir algunas reglas si estoy usando react-router. en mi caso el sitio donde estoy desplegando mi app es -> render.com